# Correct way to creating multiple QThreads

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread

I am developing an application with Qt 5.9.4 and i have a class derived on QThread

```
    class LogOperations : public QThread
    {
      Q_OBJECT
    public:
      LogOperations(QString path,QStringList args,int threadID);
      ~LogOperations();
      void setFileName(QString path);
      void setArguments(QStringList ar);
      void run();
    };
```

and there is a mainwindow which i create and start those threads in it.
First, i create a QList that holds a pointer to that QThread Class

```
QList<LogOperations *> threadList;
```

Then i am simply creating the threads like this

```
    for(int i=0;i<ls.count();i++)
    {
         threadList.append(new LogOperations(ls.at(i),args,i));
         threadList.at(i)->start();
    }
```

But if there are 5-10 threads it's working fine but if there are to many (like 20 or above) threads, the application crashes, how can i handle these threads? any thought?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code shown.  My guess would be that you have undefined behaviour somewhere due to a data race but without a [mcve] we can only guess.

Comment: usually i am getting an error that saying terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Comment: @thehilmisu it may be some memory leak, it is hard to say looking at this code. Please provide reproducible example

Comment: i am sorry that i can not provide a reproducible example. but i did change the qthread inheritance to qobject, and everything works fine except i can not use the threading features like 'msleep'